# Dragging in C# without dropping

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a map editor for my games. I had already managed to add an object to the map when the user clicks on the map. It would be handy for me to add objects in a path the user clicks mouse and drags (like the pencil in mspaint). What events do I need to register to give that effect?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: @Guy Using Mouse up/down and moved at the same time?

Comment: yes, mouse over. use a flag to know if you are draging right now.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try to code that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the main idea :

use **MouseUp() MouseDown()** and **MouseMove()** .

Set some bool to 0 - tell you if you are Dragging.

When (mouse Down) and (flag==0) then START_DRAGGING.
Then mouse move knows if you are dragging by flag==1.

When (mouse UP) and (flag == 1) you know youv'e just stopped dragging, so set flag to 0 again.